# Start a Dialog from OneSignal Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, kotlin, dialog, onesignal

Dunno if this is possible, I have read the documentation in one signal site regarding the Action Buttons and I just couldn´t find an answer.

What I´m trying to achieve, is that when user press the push notification, I´d like it to trigger a dialog when starting the main activity of my app.

For example, If I send a push notification to check updates on the husky screen, I´d like it to trigger the dialog that takes the user to the husky screen, and if I send a push notification to check updates on the chihuahua screen, I´d like it to take the user to the chihuahua screen.

I have created all my screens in same activity, and instead of moving from activities, my app hides and shows layouts.

I also kind of want to do the same with the dialogs, depeandig on the notification ID.

I´d like to create many layouts for the different dialogs I want to display, and I´d like the push notification to trigger an specific dialog depeanding on which notification ID was pressed, as an example here is the husky dialog:

```
    var builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    var inflater: LayoutInflater = layoutInflater
    var view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialghusky, null)
    builder.setView(view)
    builder.setTitle("Dogs")
    builder.setPositiveButton("Watch Updates", { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
        mainscreen.visibility = View.GONE
        ListView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        listHusky.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        listaHusky.adapter = adapterSalud
        edit_huskysearch.setText("Brown")
    })
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int -> })
    var dialog: Dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
```

This is what I would like to be displayed when user press the push notification with the husky ID.

AS you can see it hides the mainscreen and displays the screen containing the Husky list, and also sets the editText.text to "Brown" (I´m using it to filter among the list).

I´m kinda new in using this OneSignal push notifications, and so far I´m able to send them, to edit them according to my preferences, images, colors, icons, etc, I´m able to make the notification open websites when push them (but this can be achieved from the onesignal site itself so that´s not a problem).

Is there a one I can achieve this from a push notification from oneSignal or I´m totally going in the wrong direction and this can be achieved by doing something else?

Thank you in advance for your support

Regards